# Signal fires twice from gtkmm popup list

Tags: gtk, signals, gtkmm

It's been a while since I used GTK+, and the last time I did was in C, not using gtkmm and C++ as I am now.  Anyway, I have what I think should be an easy problem to solve:

I have a pop-up menu consisting of a list of radio buttons, and when I click one of them I want some action to occur.  The code goes like this:

```
    Gtk::RadioMenuItem::Group group;
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < LH_MAX; ++i )
    {
        Gtk::RadioMenuItem* pItem = new Gtk::RadioMenuItem( group, names[i], names[i] );
        pItem->set_name( names[i] );
        pItem->signal_activate().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyClass::on_item_activated) );
        pItem->show();
        m_Menu.append( *Gtk::manage(pItem) );
    }
```

The only problem I see is that `MyClass::on_item_activated` gets called twice when a previously-unselected radio button is chosen from the menu.  It's called only once when the already-selected radio button is clicked.

I'm guessing that the first firing is to say "something is no longer activate," and the second is for the new radio button activation.  Whether I'm right or wrong, the question is the same: how best can I have my handler only take action once per click?  Either I need the handler to get called only once, or I need something to check from inside it to know if the callback is a "duplicate" or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sigc::bind to supply the item as a argument to the callback function.

```
pItem->signal_activate().sigc::bind(sigc::mem_fun(*this,&MyClass::on_item_activated),pItem));
```

Then you can use item->get_active() in the callback to respond to activations only.

```
      void MyClass::on_item_activated(Gtk::RadioMenuItem* item) {
        if (item->get_active()) {
               // Do some stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: But how can you guarantee that pItem will still be valid by the time this call back happens? I tried this approach and my application crashed. pItem was returned from a Glade builder object...

Answer (score 1):

That's what I do too, connect to `signal_toggled()` and check if `get_active()` is true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish (or what MyClass is and what base classes it inherits from), but connecting to `signal_toggled()` might be more useful than `signal_activate()`

Comment: `MyClass` inherits from nothing (for the purposes of this discussion at least).  Its `on_item_activated` method is meant to open a popup window (hence calling it twice is bad).  I'll try `signal_toggled()` when I get back to this.

Answer (score 0):

/Agree with Johannes. Check if the item is activated when receiving the signal.